# How to register dependency injection in n-tier architecture application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, n-tier-architecture

I have made a n-tier architecture application where domain and services are on different project. The project is based on repository pattern. This is how I have prepared my project pattern

[image]

But however I can't find a solution to register all my interfaces and it's implementation i.e. can't register dependency injection. Here I want to register DI from `Repository` and `Services` project.

Since I found a [this](https://dzone.com/articles/using-dependency-injection-in-multiple-net-core-pr) link where it seems to have solution but however I can't resolve on my case. This is how I have prepared my code

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddCsvFileConnector(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Repository
        services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();

        // Services
        services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

And the error keeps saying

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Service.Interface.ITestService' while attempting to activate 'Api.Controller.TestController'.

Comment: As per tagging guidelines in the [help], please avoid placing tags in your question titles.

Comment: Are you calling `services.AddCsvFileConnector()` somewhere at your startup logic?

Comment: `Travel` project should reference all other projects, to be able to resolve dependencies.

Comment: @dcg - no I am not. I tried to call that in services but while adding reference to that project it says `Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency`

Comment: @ChrisHadfield Make sure that none of the class libraries reference `Travel` and like what Fabio said, make sure `Travel` references all the libraries, then call `services.AddCsvFileConnector()` in `Travel`'s `Startup.cs` file

Comment: @JohanP - I have referenced it on Implementation of repository project to access `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: Thank you all guys. I solve my problem by not making a reference of `Travel` on other projects